# Custom JVM Property is null in 8.5.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, rad

We're migrating to WAS 8.5.5 and RAD 9.  We have a legacy app that needs a custom property.  We usually set it through the JVM custom properties at : Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties.  It's always worked before.  Yet our app is getting null back from this property now.  Four sets of eyes have quadruple checked that it's spelled identically.

What to do?  Is there a way to figure out why the value appears unset to the application?  Is there an alternative way to get it into System.getProperty()?

Comment: This works in WebSphere 8.5.5 I've used before. There's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in v8.5.5 and RAD 9. Just remember to restart the server after setting this property, since it is on the JVM level and WAS needs to be restarted to pick it up.

You may print your properties using:

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
System.out.println("Properties: " + properties);
System.out.println("myCustomProperty: " + System.getProperty("myCustomProperty"));
```